# Why can't rspec and capybara connect to solr when running test suite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, rspec, capybara, homebrew

I recently had to reinstalled Homebrew, postgres, my RVM ruby and gemset and my rails app. Now I have a ton of failing tests because the app can't connect to solr. Here is an example of the errors I'm getting:

```
 Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL:        Can't assign requested address - connect(2)
```

Here's the output of one of failures. I'm getting this error on all of them:
https://gist.github.com/da7311560f7b6df6354b

It seems that the problem is that QtWebKit library is not loaded, but I don't understand why this is happening. I tried removing QT from my homebrew cellar and reinstalling it but that didn't work.

Any ideas on what the problem might be? Also, here's my gemfile:

https://gist.github.com/640ed0daa704865433b3

Comment: Why do you believe this is connected to solr?

Comment: Because the failure message has occurred in the past when solr wasn't running - Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Can't assign requested address - connect(2)

Comment: It might not be related to Solr, that was just my guess.

Comment: It's almost certainly not SOLR related. that's a standard socket error. It looks like when the capybara webkit browser attempts to connect to rails. Is this every request, or only certain requests? Also: what version of capybara-webkit is installed?

Comment: This was indeed a problem with capybara-webkit. I ran rvm implode and installed everything from scratch and I'm not longer getting those failures. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Jesse!